# How to get the first day of the current year?

Tags: php, datetime

I need to use PHP DateTime to get the first day of the current year. I've tried:

```
$year = new DateTime('first day of this year');
var_dump($year);
```

But this seems to be returning the first day of the current month: **2014-09-01 09:28:56**

Why? How do I correctly get the first day of the current year?

Comment: Is solution `$year = new DateTime('first day of january');` not ok?

Comment: Plus, this should work too `new \DateTime('first day of January this year')` or `new \DateTime('last day of December next year')` for example...

Comment: But, does someone know, why `'first day of this year'` returns a valid Date but not the first day of this year? Makes it sense?

Answer (score 55):

Or use only text in the `strtotime` function:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january this year'));
```

Answer (score 49):

Your relative date format `'first day of this year'` is correct by returning the first day of the month because of the definition of `first day of`:

> Sets the day of the first of the current month. This phrase is best
>   used together with a month name following it. ([See PHP-doc](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php))

To get the first day of the current year with the relative format you can use something like this:

```
'first day of January ' . date('Y')
```

Comment: or better: strtotime('first day of january this year')

Comment: There are some time zone related nuances to this answer. I recorded those in a separate answer here. Check it out.

Answer (score 42):

```
echo date('l',strtotime(date('Y-01-01')));
```

Answer (score 15):

You can get the current date and then set day and month to 1:

```
$year = new DateTime();
$year->setDate($year->format('Y'), 1, 1);
```

Optionally, you can set the time to midnight:

```
$year->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get first day of current year just use this code

```
echo date("l", strtotime('first day of January '.date('Y') ));
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically date('Y') returns the value of current year. and the first day of each year starts like 2000-01-01.

So this will help you to get exact output.

```
$firstdate = date( 'Y' ) . '-01-01';
```

Comment: Basically date('Y') returns the value of current year. and the first day of each year starts like 2000-01-01. So `$firstdate = date('Y').'01-01';` returns the value of the first day of current year.

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!

Comment: for the current year  1st date this will do $startDate= date('Y-01-01');

Answer (score 6):

> Just wanted to record some nuance with the answer by `lorem monkey`

The suggested method might cause issues with when using time zones.

scenario: consider current system time is `2018-01-01 00:20:00 UTC` and system default time zone is set to UTC.

`date('Y')` will give you **2018**

if you are doing something like:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('first day of january '.date('Y'), new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

This will compute to `'first day of january 2018'` but you actually needed the first date of your current year in America/New_York, which is still 2017.

> Stop dropping the ball man, its not new year yet!

So it is better to just do

```
$startDate = new DateTime('first day of january', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

And then do the modifications as needed by using the `DateTime::modify()` function.

> Relative date formats are fun.
>
> My scenario: I wanted to get the bounds of this year as in `2018-01-01 00:00:00` to `2018-12-31 23:59:59`

This can be achieved in two ways with relative date formats.

one way is to use the `DateTime::modify()` function on the object.

```
$startDate = (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("America/New_York")));
$endDate = (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("America/New_York")));

$startDate->modify("january")
    ->modify("first day of this month")
    ->modify("midnight");
    
$endDate->modify("next year")
    ->modify("january")
    ->modify("first day of this month")
    ->modify("midnight")->modify("-1 second");

var_dump([$startDate, $endDate]);
```

Try out here: https://www.tehplayground.com/Qk3SkcrCDkNJoLK2

Another way to do this is to separate the relative strings with a comma like so:

```
$startDate = (new DateTime('first day of january', new DateTimeZone("America/New_York")));
$endDate = (new DateTime('next year, first day of january, -1 second', new DateTimeZone("America/New_York")));
var_dump([$startDate, $endDate]);
```

Try out here: https://www.tehplayground.com/hyCqXLRBlhJbCyks

Answer (score 3):

Following is the code snippet for getting first and last day of the year.

```
 $firstDayOfYear = date('Y-01-01');
 $lastDayOfYear = date('Y-12-t');
```

Comment: `date('Y')` returns current year. `date('t')` return last date of the current month.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link -- http://davidhancock.co/2013/11/get-the-firstlast-day-of-a-week-month-quarter-or-year-in-php/

```
 function firstDayOf($period, DateTime $date = null)
{
    $period = strtolower($period);
    $validPeriods = array('year', 'quarter', 'month', 'week');

    if ( ! in_array($period, $validPeriods))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Period must be one of: ' . implode(', ', $validPeriods));

    $newDate = ($date === null) ? new DateTime() : clone $date;

    switch ($period) {
        case 'year':
            $newDate->modify('first day of january ' . $newDate->format('Y'));
            break;
        case 'quarter':
            $month = $newDate->format('n') ;

            if ($month < 4) {
                $newDate->modify('first day of january ' . $newDate->format('Y'));
            } elseif ($month > 3 && $month < 7) {
                $newDate->modify('first day of april ' . $newDate->format('Y'));
            } elseif ($month > 6 && $month < 10) {
                $newDate->modify('first day of july ' . $newDate->format('Y'));
            } elseif ($month > 9) {
                $newDate->modify('first day of october ' . $newDate->format('Y'));
            }
            break;
        case 'month':
            $newDate->modify('first day of this month');
            break;
        case 'week':
            $newDate->modify(($newDate->format('w') === '0') ? 'monday last week' : 'monday this week');
            break;
    }

    return $newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in PHP 5.3.10 this works

```
$myDate = new \DateTime(date("Y")."-01-01");                                                                                                                                                                        
echo $myDate->format("Y-m-d");
```

In PHP 5.4 and upper you can put all together

```
echo (new \DateTime(date("Y")."-01-01"))->format("Y-m-d")
```

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter @Glavić said already

`$year = new DateTime('first day of January');`

is the solution.

To me it did make sense semantically that "this year" should return midnight of the first day of the year, but indeed it does not!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dt = date('m/d/Y',time());

echo 'First day : '. date("01/01/Y", strtotime($dt)).' - Last day : '. date("m/t/Y", strtotime($dt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting first and last day of the current year using DateTime object.

```
$currentDate = new \DateTime("NOW");

$yearStartString = $currentDate->format("Y")."-01-01 00:00:00";
$yearEndString = $currentDate->format("Y")."-12-31 23:59:59";

$yearStartDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $yearStartString);
$yearEndDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $yearEndString);
```